# How to make a scrollable drag&drop grid in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a grid which is scrollable like the default Flatlist, but with drag&drop functionality to reorder elements.

[image: current grid screenshot]
I used [react-native-draggable-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-grid) which is almost perfect, I just can't make the grid scrollable. I'm very new to react native, any help would be greatly appreciated!

After a basic react native init, I installed the DraggableGrid package.
My App.js looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {DraggableGrid} from 'react-native-draggable-grid';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  users=[
    { key: '1', nameval: '1' },
    { key: '2', nameval: '2' },
    { key: '3', nameval: '3' },
    { key: '4', nameval: '4' },
    { key: '5', nameval: '5' },
    { key: '6', nameval: '6' },
    { key: '7', nameval: '7' },
    { key: '8', nameval: '8' },
    { key: '9', nameval: '9' },
    { key: '10', nameval: '10' }
  ];

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DraggableGrid data={this.users} numColumns={2}
          renderItem={({item})=>
            <View style={{width:150, height:150, backgroundColor:'#AA0022'}}>
              <Text>item</Text>
            </View>
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#00FCFF',
  }
});
```

The drag&drop functionality works while I don't try to drag an element to the bottom of the screen. I was expecting it to auto-scroll down and show other elements but this is not happening. The grid is not scrollable at all.

I was thinking to put the whole DraggableGrid in a ScrollView, but I'm afraid that way there would be no cell reusability (like in Android RecyclerView)